# How to create a binary value to capture null values in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, null

Here is a simplified version of my current dataset:

```
v1    v2     v3
null  b      c
a     b      c
a     null   c
```

I want to create a new column called 'v4' that would be a 1, ONLY if v1 is null, and 0, if v1 was not null.

The desired output would look like this

```
v1    v2     v3 v4
null  b      c  1
a     b      c  0
a     null   c  0
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag when posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data:

```
df$v4=sapply(df$v1,function(f){as.numeric(f=="null")})
```

Generally, while reading data in `r`, you can specify the string representing null values ("null", "NA", "NULL","") in data in the `na.strings` parameter of functions like `read.csv` or `fread` which are then converted to `NA` in the R data.frame. In that case, you can modify the above code to:

```
df$v4=sapply(df$v1,function(f){as.numeric(is.na(f))})
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!